# Change password AND public key for standard user pi

Tags: ssh, password

I want to SSH into my Raspberry Pi, but for security reasons also don't want to keep the standard password `raspberry` for the standard user `pi`. There fore I used `passwd` to change `pi`'s password. However, when I then try to ssh I get the errors

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

These errors are also the subject of a number of other threads, but none have answers that solve the problem for me.

I think it has something to do with the public key and it not changing with the password when one uses `passwd`. The reason being that if I change the password back to `raspberry` I can SSH just fine.

-EDIT- Verbose ssh added

```
-bash-4.1$ ssh -v pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nfs/shijgenaar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

Comment: Can you run `ssh -v <your_raspberrypi>`? That would provide you a much more verbose error message.

Comment: *"I think it has something to do with the public key and it not changing with the password when one uses passwd."* -> No, public keys and passwords are completely separate methodologies.  You can enable either or both but normally you would only use one or the other (it might be possible to configure it to require both, but that is not the default case).  If you are using a password and it fails, chances are it is because the password is incorrect.  You can try connecting with `ssh -vv` to get more details and on the pi side, have a look in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: @goldilocks I have added the verbose

Comment: It still looks as though the problem is the wrong password.  You should try it with something simple and ascii, e.g., `abc123`, and double check the `pi` user can log in locally with that. The stuff about the public/private keys is just there because you have some on the remote computer and if `sshd` says it will accept them, the `ssh` client will try and apply them automatically.  When that fails it falls back to password.  You will see much the same thing if you do this when the password is working.

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you. Apparently the keyboard I was using on the Raspberry Pi has a different keyboard layout than the one on my laptop ^^' *facepalm*

Comment: It's probably worth noting that as an answer for posterity, lol.  I think you will have to wait a few hours to do so (the system won't let you answer your own question in the first 24 hours unless you meet a certain rep threshold) but if after that you have time to summarize the problem please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was indeed using the wrong password to login, seeing my laptop's keyboard has a different layout than the keyboard attached to my RaspberryPi. I can now SSH without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have pub key in .ssh/authorized_keys?
You need to enabled key based authentication in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers pi
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM no
```

Maybe there is a typo while accessing the RPi with ssh?

Comment: Is there an option to login via SSH using just my user password for pi? I have tried `PubkeyAuthentication no PasswordAuthentication yes` but it doesn't help